# TypeScript type information for Node require

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a Node server created as:

```
function createHttpServer(app) {
    var http = require('http');
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    return server;
}
```

I am in the process of migrating our `.js` code into `.ts` code and I notice that when the extension is `.js`, I get type information for `createServer`. However, when I switch to `.ts` it becomes `any`, so I struggle with the correct typings.

This is what my `tsconfig.json` file looks like:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "./out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "types": [
            "node"
        ],
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "pretty": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

Why, despite the `node` types, do I get `any` instead of the correct type information?

Comment: If you see the type within your create server function, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but only when I am using the `.js` extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `import` instead of `require`

```
import * as http from "http";

function createHttpServer(app) {
  // var http = require("http");
  var server = http.createServer(app);
  return server;
}
```